# Sorting Datastructures using comparator

Tags: java, data-structures, comparator

I am trying to sort an array (`ads`, of type `ETstrain`) by one of the instance variables (`distancefrom`). How can I do this? I have tried using a comparator and then a sorting function. Is there a better way/ do I have any logical fallacies?

```
abstract class distanceComparator implements Comparator<ETstrain> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ETstrain a, ETstrain b) {
    return a.distancefrom < b.distancefrom ? -1 : a.distancefrom == b.distancefrom ? 0 : 1;
        }
}

public static <ETstrain> void sort(ads[] a,
        Comparator<ETstrain> b)
```

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I would however suggest using `Integer.compare(a.distancefrom, b.distancefrom)` (or `Float`/`Double.compare`) or, if you're on Java 8, use `Comparator.comparing(ets -> ets.distancefrom)`.

Comment: just return a.distancefrom - b.distancefrom... Simpler

Comment: @ControlAltDel, that's a [terrible idea](http://ideone.com/zdjuU9).

Comment: @ControlAltDel That would result in an overflow at some point.

Comment: @aioobe Yes, but if `distancefrom` can be only positive (and I imagine that distance is always positive), it should work fine.

Comment: @KrzysztofKosmatka in this specific case, distancefrom can be negative since it is the vertical distance from a line. I do think it would result in an overflow quite quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
Arrays.sort(yourETStrainArray, distanceComparator);
```

If you have a List instead of an array, use:

```
Collections.sort(yourETStrainList, distanceComparator);
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(ETstrain[] ads,Comparator <? ETstrain>distanceComparator);`
Gives me 
 Syntax error on token "sort", Identifier expected after this token
and 
Syntax error on token "ETstrain", delete this token

and
`Arrays.sort(ads,distanceComparator);`
Syntax error on token "(", delete this token on both parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
public class distanceComparator implements Comparator<ETstrain> {
    @Override
    public int compare(ETstrain a, ETstrain b) {
        return a.distancefrom < b.distancefrom ? -1
                : a.distancefrom == b.distancefrom ? 0 : 1;
    }
    public <ETstrain> void sort(ETstrain[] ads,
            Comparator<? super ETstrain> distanceComparator){
        Arrays.sort(ads, distanceComparator);
    }
}
```